# Understanding frequency sort with lambda

Tags: python-3.x, collections, counter

I have this code which does a frequency sort with key=lambda x: (count[x])

```
nums = [1,1,2,2,2,3]
count = collections.Counter(nums)
output = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: (count[x]))
```

this gives the output
[3,1,1,2,2,2]

I would like to know why [3,1,2] isn't the output? How are the keys being repeated from the counter?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are still sorting `nums` which contains all the elements (with duplication/repetition). `key=lambda x: count[x]` only decides the order in which the elements are ordered in.

An equivalent but less efficient (`O(n2)` instead of `O(n)`) code is

```
sorted(nums, key=lambda x: nums.count(x))
```